# Column A or Column B required MS Access DB

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I'm in the situation where I would like to enforce the requirement where a record must contain either one column or another at a data level, I'm not sure whether it's achievable.

I've got an `Enquiry` table which is used for new enquiries being recorded; this can either be based on an existing customer, which is contained within the `Customer` table or prospective customer which will be created and stored within a `ProspectiveCustomer` table.

```
 Enquiry
-----------------------------------------------
 EnquiryID  | CustomerID | ProspectID | Notes | 
       3    |     2      |     null   |   x   | 
       4    |     null   |     3      |   y   |
```

There must be a record number in either CustomerID or ProspectID, but not in both. Is this achievable at a data level alone? or would I have to simply validate my inputs in this way and hope for the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of a scenario, where you can have a `MasterUser` table that will asign `ID` to both Customer and Prospect, auto incremented `PKId` can be named as `UserID` of the table.

let Say you create a table `MasterUser` and stored common details like names etc. that both Customer and Prospect have, now the unique info can be better moved to table `Customer` and `ProspectiveCustomer`.

Now as you have uniqueId for each user, no matter the user is Prospect or Customer.

So you Enquiry table will be something like

```
Enquiry
-----------------------------------------------
 EnquiryID  | UserID| Notes | 
       3    |    2  |   x   | 
       4    |    3  |   y   |
```

Comment: That's a good idea @vijayp thanks, it will also support the behavior where a `ProspectiveCustomer` gets converted into `Customer` once a quotation is raised.

Comment: When you say: _`MasterUser` table that will assign `ID` to both `Customer` and `Prospect`, auto incremented `PKId` can be named as `UserID` of the table._ Would you suggest that I used a trigger (or, for MS Access, data macro) to create the subsequent record in `Customer/ProspectiveCustomer` upon creation of the `MasterUser`?

Comment: Well, you can go for trigger, or you can go for a `Stored Procedure` for the entry in `MasterUser` and subsequent record in `Customer/ProspectiveCustomer`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Customers and Prospects are really subclasses of a superclass, one that might be called "Contacts".  If so, you might consider storing them in the same table, with a type field to say whether it's a customer or a prospect.

If that oversimplifies your case for some reason, you might want to do some research on "Class Table Inheritance".  Fowler has a good presentation of this topic on the web.

I've never had to implement a complex case of superclass/subclass in Access,  so you might want to look before you leap.

Comment: In case customer have data which prospect don't have and vice-versa, then it will have big number of columns with `NULL`.

Comment: If this is the case, that's where the concept of class table inheritance applies.

Comment: Thanks Walter, I'm familiar with the class inheritance concept from my OOP background and I think this is what @vijayp was getting at with his `MasterUser` example.

Right now, I'm in the early conceptual design stages which means that I don't have much to lose by leaping in and having a go at modeling a relationship like this.

Comment: There is no real Polymorphism support in MS Access, if there was then I probably wouldn't be asking the question. The key for me here is to create a data structure which logically lends itself to this type of approach.

Comment: Just to make things a little bit more complicated, each `Customer` will have a `Contact` associated with them whereas a `Prospect` will not need that level of complexity, at least, not until they have a quotation carried out and become a `Customer`.

Comment: It's good that you're familiar with the class inheritance concept.  The class table inheritance concept is ever so slightly different.  It's an attempt to bridge the gap between relational design and object design.  It's well worth learning, in addition to what you already know.  And it isn't a silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of whether it's possible to require either one field *or* another but not both: yes, it's possible, but you'll need to set that up as an Access ANSI-92 SQL `check` constraint in your table, using the `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` DAO method. It's not possible using the Access UI, but once you do it like I describe below, Access will enforce it at the database engine level (i.e. you won't be able to violate the constraint even by directly opening up the table).

You will need to run something like the following in a VBA sub:

```
strSQL = "         alter table Enquiry "
strSQL = strSQL & "add constraint Enquiry_require_either_CustomerID_or_ProspectID check ( "
strSQL = strSQL & "     (CustomerID is not null and ProspectID is null) "
strSQL = strSQL & "  or (CustomerID is null and ProspectID is not null) "
strSQL = strSQL & ")"

CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
```

To do the converse, i.e. remove the constraint, you would need to run the following SQL similarly:

```
alter table Enquiry
drop constraint Enquiry_require_either_CustomerID_or_ProspectID
```